# ehcache asynchronous write/put example

Tags: caching, asynchronous, ehcache, put, in-memory-database

Hi I'm trying to implement ehcache into our product to handle caching large amounts of data. While doing some research I saw that asynchronously caching can be beneficial for larger queries so that they can run in the background. Unfortunately I don't know how to implement this and was hoping for some help. Any simple example in java for an asynchronous write/put of an element (key,value) would be really helpful.

Thanks